# How to optimize the following code in Perl?

Tags: regex, excel, perl

How to optimize the following Excel code with hashes and arrays in Perl?Is there any possible ways to reduce the lines of code for the following examples?

**Example 1:-**

```
$style = $workbook->add_format();
$style->set_bold();
$style->set_bg_color('blue');
$style->set_align('center');
$style->set_border(1);
$style->set_border_color('black');
```

**Example2:-**

```
$worksheet->write_col("A2",$file1);
$worksheet->write_col("B2",$file2);
$worksheet->write_col("C2",$file3,$style);
$worksheet->write_col("D2",$file4,$style);
```

Comment: For the first example: You could try add properties to the [`add_format()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#FORMAT-METHODS) method., for example `$style = $workbook->add_format(bold => 0, bg_color => 'blue', ...)`. For the second example: you could use a hash with the first parameter as a key. But it depends on the other code in your script. If you show more code, it would be easier to give advice

Comment: @Hakon I don't have proper code.I just need an idea.That's why i posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use [`add_format()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#add_format(%25properties)) with a hash and [`write()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#write($row,-$column,-$token,-$format)) in a `for` loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('formats.xls');


my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('Introduction');

my %format = (bold => 0, bg_color => 'blue', align => 'center',
          border => 1, border_color => 'black');
my $style = $workbook->add_format(%format);
$worksheet->write(4, 0, 'This workbook demonstrates some of',  $style);
$worksheet->write(5, 0, 'the formatting options provided by',  $style);
$worksheet->write(6, 0, 'the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module.', $style);

my ( $file1, $file2, $file3, $file4 ) = qw(file1 file2 file3 file4);
my %write_col = ( A2 => [$file1], B2 => [$file2],
                  C2 => [$file3, $style], D2 => [$file4, $style] );
$worksheet->write($_, @{$write_col{$_}}) for keys %write_col;

$workbook->close();
```

Comment: Can You explain this line ?                                                                                             my ( $file1, $file2, $file3, $file4 ) = qw(file1 file2 file3 file4);

Comment: @Crazycoder It just sets some dummy value for the variable `$file1`, `$file2`, ... Just use your values instead :) And `qw(a  b)` is the same as `('a', 'b')`, see [`perldoc perlop`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for more information

Comment: Your explanation gave me a good idea and thanks for providing more information.